# Derivative of trace functions using chain rule

Tags: matrices, derivatives, trace, chain-rule

Let us consider $\text{trace}(f(AA^\top))$ where $f$ is some smooth function and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$. Here, function $f$ is a function of matrices (c.f., Higham's books). If $f(x) = x$, then $\text{trace}(f(AA^\top)) = \|A\|_F^2$ (Frobenius norm) and if $f(x) = x^{p/2}$, then $\text{trace}(f(AA^\top))$ is related to Schatten-$p$ norm.

I would like to derivative $\text{trace}(f(AA^\top))$ with respect to matrix $A$. 
Let $g: X\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \text{trace}(f(X)) \in \mathbb{R}$ and $h: A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \rightarrow A A^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. By chain rule, it holds that
$$
\frac{\partial g(h(A))}{\partial A} = \frac{\partial g(h(A))}{\partial h} \frac{\partial h(A)}{\partial A}.
$$
To the best of my knowledge, $\frac{\partial g(h(A))}{\partial h} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\frac{\partial h(A)}{\partial A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n \times n \times m}$. 
I was confused whether those two terms are productable or not. However, when $p=2$, this corresponds to square of Frobenius norm and its derivative is known as $2 A$.

Any comment or advise would be highly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Let's denote the derivative of the function with a prime
$$\eqalign {
f'(x) &= \frac{df(x)}{dx} \cr
}$$
The differential of the trace of the function applied to a matrix argument is
$$\eqalign {
\lambda &= {\rm tr}\big(f(M)\big) \cr
d\lambda &= f'(M)^T:dM \cr
}$$ where the colon denotes the double-contraction product, i.e.
$\,\,A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$

In the case that $\,M=AA^T\,$ note that $M$ is symmetric, so $f'(M)^T=f'(M)$. Now we can use the above differential to find the gradient with respect to $A$ 
$$\eqalign {
d\lambda
 &= f'(M):(dA\,A^T+A\,dA^T) \cr
 &= f'(M):dA\,A^T + f'(M):A\,dA^T \cr
 &= f'(M):dA\,A^T + f'(M)^T:dA\,A^T \cr
 &= 2f'(M):dA\,A^T \cr
 &= 2f'(AA^T)A:dA \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial A} &= 2f'(AA^T)A \cr
}$$

Comment: As a concrete example, let $$\lambda={\rm tr}(\sin(AA^T))$$ then the above derivation tells us that $$\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial A}=2\cos(AA^T)A$$

Comment: Using your answer, I tried to solve https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3181893/product-rule-for-trace-of-matrix-functions question, does it look correct?

Comment: @DushyantSahoo This answer assumes that functions will be applied _matrix-wise_ but your new question specifies that functions are applied _element-wise_ -- so you cannot use this result to answer that question.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R})$ be the vector space of real $n \times n$ matrices. With $f \, : \, \mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R}) \, \rightarrow \, \mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R})$ a function which is differentiable on $\mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R})$, let $g \, : \, X \in \mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R}) \, \mapsto \, \mathrm{tr}\big( f(X) \big)$.

1. Because $\mathrm{tr}$ is linear, the differential of $g$ at $X$ is the **composition** of $\mathrm{tr}$ and the differential of $f$ at $X$ : for $H \in \mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R})$, it follows from the chain rule that:

$$ D_{X}g \cdot H = \mathrm{D}_{f(X)} \mathrm{tr} \cdot \big( D_{X}f \cdot H \big) = \mathrm{tr}\big( D_{X}f \cdot H \big). $$

As a result : $D_{X}g = \mathrm{tr} \circ \mathrm{D}_{X}f$.

2. If $f \, : \, X \in \mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R}) \, \mapsto \, X X^{\top} \in \mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R})$, the differential of $f$ at $X$ is computed as follows: for $H \in \mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R})$,

$$ f(X+H) = (X+H)(X+H)^{\top} = XX^{\top} + XH^{\top} + HX^{\top} + HH^{\top}. $$

It follows from the definition of the differential that :

$$ D_{X}f \cdot H = XH^{\top} + HX^{\top}. $$

Finally :

> $$ D_{X}g \cdot H = \mathrm{tr}\big( XH^{\top} + HX^{\top} \big) = 2\mathrm{tr}(XH^{\top}). $$

This also gives you the gradient of $g$ at $X$: $\nabla_{X}g = 2X$.