# Product rule for trace of matrix functions

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, trace, chain-rule

I am trying to find the gradient of $f(Z_2) = \|A - Zg(Z_1g(Z_2)) \|_F^2$ with respect to $Z_2$ where $g$ function is applied to each matrix element wise such that $i,j$ element of matrix $g(X) = g(X_{ij})$, and $A, Z, Z_1, Z_2 \in R^{n \times n}$. An example of $g$ is an exponential function, tanh function, etc. I am trying to do a gradient descent to find the minimum of $f(Z_2)$ for which I require the gradient. I know $$f(Z_2) = trace((A - Zg(Z_1g(Z_2)))^T(A - Zg(Z_1g(Z_2))))$$  $$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial f(Z_2)}{\partial Z_2} = \frac{\partial trace(-A^TZg(Z_1g(Z_2)) - (Zg(Z_1g(Z_2)))^TA + (Zg(Z_1g(Z_2)))^T(Zg(Z_1g(Z_2)))) }{\partial Z_2}$$
I am not sure how to use the chain rule to find the above gradient.

Edit1 : I tried to solve a smaller problem by taking $f(Z_2) = \|A - g(Z_2) \|_F^2$ . In this case 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f(Z_2)}{\partial Z_2} &= \frac{\partial }{\partial Z_2}trace(A^TA -g(Z_2)^TA - A^Tg(Z_2) + g(Z_2)^Tg(Z_2))  \\
& = -A^Tg'(Z_2) -g'(Z_2)^TA + g'(Z_2)^Tg(Z_2) + g(Z_2)^Tg'(Z_2)
\end{align*}
For above derivation, I have used [Derivative of trace functions using chain rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357091/derivative-of-trace-functions-using-chain-rule?rq=1). Does the above solution look correct?

Comment: Please, give examples of functions $g$ you want to use.

Comment: @JeanMarie I want to use functions such as tanh or exponential.

Comment: Why such a sophisticated expression at once ? Why not begin by $f(Z_2) = \|A -g(Z_2) \|_F^2$ ? What is the motivation of your complicated expression ? Is it a 2 layers neural network or something like that ? If yes, why don't you say it ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I am trying to solve a matrix decomposition problem where I have to put constraints on the matrices to get a set of required properties. It is not a neural network.

Comment: But don't you think, reversing my remark, that, as operation $Zg(Z_1g(Z_2)$ looks like a modelization of a neural network (with "a kind of" objective $A$ to be backpropagated  (?) with "a kind of" sigmoid attenuation brought by $\tanh$ for example) you could use a neural network for getting an approximate solution ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, you are right, but the problem which I posted is just a subproblem where I can not approximate the matrices by using a neural network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for an elementwise function, the differential involves the elementwise/Hadamard product.
$$\eqalign{
\def\g{{\large\Gamma}}
dg(X) &= g'(X) \odot dX \,=\, \g_X\odot dX \cr
}$$
Define a cascade of variables.
$$\eqalign{
X &= g(Z_2) \cr
Y &= Z_1X \cr
W &= g(Y) \cr
V &= ZW \cr
U &= V-A \cr
f &= U:U \cr
}$$
Take the differential of the last variable, and reverse the cascade.
$$\eqalign{
df
 &= 2\,U:dU \cr
 &= 2\,U:dV \cr
 &= 2\,U:Z\,dW \cr
 &= 2\,Z^TU:dW \cr
 &= 2\,Z^TU:\g_Y\odot dY \cr
 &= 2\,\g_Y\odot(Z^TU):dY \cr
 &= 2\,\g_Y\odot(Z^TU):Z_1\,dX \cr
 &= 2\,Z_1^T(\g_Y\odot(Z^TU)):\g_{Z_2}\odot dZ_2 \cr
 &= 2\,\g_{Z_2}\odot(Z_1^T(\g_Y\odot(Z^TU))):dZ_2 \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial Z_2}
 &= 2\,\g_{Z_2}\odot(Z_1^T(\g_Y\odot(Z^TU))) \cr
 &= 2\,g'(Z_2)\odot\Big(Z_1^T\big(g'(Y)\odot(Z^TU)\big)\Big) \cr
\cr
}$$
**NB:**   A colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$\,\,A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$

Comment: In the final answer, it should be transpose of $Z_1$.

Comment: Yes! Good catch. I have updated my post.